# ExtJs / Sencha : how to highlight a grid row after insert?

Tags: grid, highlight, extjs

I want to create such a grid:
http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html

Actually I already did, but I want to highlight the last inserted row of my grid (in extjs this is the function highlight(), which does a yellowfade on the element).

I didn't actually succeed in doing this... my problem is that I can't get the row I just inserted, and thus obviously I can't highlight it.
Any clues?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

You only need to do this (here for row number one):

```
var row = grid.getView().getRow(0);
Ext.get(row).highlight();
```

It's that easy.

Comment: ExtJS 4.x: use `getNode` instead of `getRow`.

Answer (score 1):

The code has

```
store.insert(0, p);
```

So don't you just highlight row zero immediately after that statement?

Comment: Yes, that s actually the case in the editable grid. But I want a solution that works for other grids. 
Actually I want to implement this:
http://37signals.com/svn/archives/000558.php

I found a solution, as written below (highlight function)

Answer (score 1):

yes sorry for answering too late,
use Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel and than use selectLastRow function u can easily will be able to point it out :)

Comment: +1 Tried 3 or 4 other methods posted on SO and around online about how to highlight a row, and using the methods in `RowSelectionModel` was the first that actually worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ext.data.store has a add listener which is passed an index at which records were inserted

`add : ( Store this, Ext.data.Record[] records, Number index )`

Comment: Yes this seems to be a good way of finding the item. But still how can I get access to the grid, such as let's say grid.GetElement(index) ? I can't find something like that.

Comment: See Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel

Answer (score 0):

This would go inside of your add/create button event.  The code `this.getSelectionModel().select(0);` will highlight the first row since we inserted into position 0, we are selecting position 0.  This code works with ExtJS 4.2.0.

```
    var rec = Ext.create('App.model.GridModel', {
        id: '123',
        name: 'ABC'
    });

    this.store.insert(0, rec);  
    this.getSelectionModel().select(0);
```